# Iframe vs Ajax into div - problems and considerations

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a requirement that i seek advice for.
I need to load a page B as part of page A. Page A could be any random customers website basically.
I need the background of Page B to be transparent, or to somehow inherit the background of page A.

I tried iframes, but i not sure how to get Page B to inherit Page A's background.

I considered using Ajax (jquery) in Page A to load Page B into a div within Page A, like so:
    
    ....
    $("#remotepage").load("PageB.php");

But in doing so I'm worried that if Page A has included a jquery library, that it might conflict with Page Bs included jquery library, which may not even be of the same version.

I'm basically trying to develop a page that is plug and play with several customer websites, to make it seem as part of my customer website.
Please advice me the best way to go about this?

Comment: Too broad? Ok. My Page B is a php form which makes use of jquery to provide date popups and fadeins and fade outs. Page A is any generic customer website. I don't really now how much more specific i can get. I'm seeking a recommended overall solution. Not a code fix.

Comment: You could easily do that if you use a template engine, like Smarty: http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: well it seems i came across a possible solution. Using allowtransparency="true" on the iframe tag, and by setting the embedded page as transparent, along the lines of <body style="background: transparent">. I'm gonna play with it further to test for browser compatibility issues before i mark this as an acceptable answer.